# Filebeat merge several lines from mysql-slow.log into one line

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I'm trying to analyze mysql-slow.log by using Filebeat Logstash and Elasticsearch. I have messages in mysql-slow.log file that look like this:

```
# Time: 2019-11-08T20:02:05.474508Z
# User@Host: user[user] @ localhost []  Id:     2
# Query_time: 0.000716  Lock_time: 0.000223 Rows_sent: 2  Rows_examined: 2
SET timestamp=1573243325;
select * from Persons;
```

First I try to make Filebeat send this log message with 5 lines to elasticsearch but all of them together in one line.

I set multiline input in filebeat.yml

```
multiline.pattern = `^\#`
multiline.negate = true
multiline.match = after
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and elasticsearch recieves lines separately

1. message --> # Time: 2019-11-08T20:02:05.474508Z
2. message --> # User@Host: user[user] @ localhost []  Id:     2
   and so on...

I want to recieve it in one message in the following format:

```
# Time: 2019-11-08T20:02:05.474508Z # User@Host: user[user] @ localhost []  Id:     2 # Query_time: 0.000716  Lock_time: 0.000223 Rows_sent: 2  Rows_examined: 2 SET timestamp=1573243325; select * from Persons;
```

Comment: Your `multiline.pattern` will match any line starting with a `#`, try to change it to `^\#[[:space:]]Time` so it will match only lines starting with `# Time`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I changed ```multiline.pattern``` to ```^\#[[:space:]]Time``` but with no result it sends me the log in the same format :((

Comment: There is something wrong on your filebeat or logstash config, I've just tested the pattern and it work, I will post the configs I've used as an asnwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your multiline pattern is wrong, it will match any line that starts with an `#`, so each of your first three lines in your example will be an event for filebeat/logstash.

You need to change your multiline pattern to match only the first line of your event, which is the line starting with `# Time`.

The following filebeat configuration worked on my tests.

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /opt/data/stackoverflow/*.log
  multiline.pattern: '^\#[[:space:]]Time'
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["elk:5044"]
```

The logstash pipeline simples listens on `5044` and outputs to elasticsearch, and then the result is the following.

[image]

As you can see all the file lines are indexed as a single event on elasticsearch.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your output is the same that I have. I was thinking of sending these 5 lines as one line into logstash so I can parse for user, query time, query etc because I don't know how to do it different way. When I put filter into logstash config file it gives me tag grokfailure or something like that...

Comment: You will need to use a mutate filter with gsub to remove the line breaks `\n` to convert it to one single line, just look into the json of the document and you will see that there are some line breaks.

Comment: So it is not a problem recieve multiple lines with logstash and parse it? Thank you for your reply!